# How to detect the end of scroll of a webivew

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I have a custom `WebView` with the following code:

```
public class ObservableWebView extends WebView {

    private OnScrollChangedCallback mOnScrollChangedCallback;

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedCallback != null) mOnScrollChangedCallback.onScroll(l, t);
    }

    public OnScrollChangedCallback getOnScrollChangedCallback() {
        return mOnScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedCallback(final OnScrollChangedCallback onScrollChangedCallback) {
        mOnScrollChangedCallback = onScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Implement in the activity/fragment/view that you want to listen to the webview
     */
    public static interface OnScrollChangedCallback {
        public void onScroll(int l, int t);
    }
}
```

I use the following method to detect whether scroll has reached the end:

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(int l, int t) {
        int tek = (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * webView.getScale());
        if(tek - webView.getScrollY() == webView.getHeight())
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Problem is it doesn't always work and fails sometimes. Is there are surer way of detecting the end of scroll of a webview that is backward compatible all the way to api level 16?

Comment: When does it fail? Certain versions of Android that are < API 16?

Comment: No, I'm running api 24 but it fails sometimes to capture the end of a scroll.

Comment: What's the message in the log when it fails?

Comment: I only use the toast to log when it reaches the end. So if it doesnt show, it didnt work. I use the same webview to load 2 different pages, and it works for only one of them but not the other.

Comment: `getScale()` is a deprecated method. From the documentation `This method was deprecated in API level 17.
This method is prone to inaccuracy due to race conditions between the web rendering and UI threads; prefer onScaleChanged(WebView, float, float).`